# Translating C into MIPS Assembly

Tags: c, sorting, assembly, mips

So I have been at this for awhile now, and I just can't seem to figure it out.  I am translating a C insertion sort into MIPS to sort a list of strings.  Here is the important C code (str_lt compares the two strings. String_lessthan):

```
void insertSort(char *a[], size_t length) {

 int i, j;

 for(i = 1; i < length; i++) {
     char *value = a[i];
     for (j = i-1; j >= 0 && str_lt(value, a[j]); j--) {
         a[j+1] = a[j];
     }
     a[j+1] = value;
 }
}
```

and here is what I have for my MIPS assembly To make the array, I aligned each string by 5 and passed the front of the array as $a2 :

```
insertSort: 
    subu $sp, $sp, 32   
    sw $ra, 20($sp)
    sw $fp, 16($sp)
    li $t2, 0
    addi $t2, $t2, 1    #t2 = i
    move $t6, $a2       #t6 = value

loop1:  
    bge $t2, 16, endloop1 
    subi $t3, $t2, 1    #t3 = j
    la $t7, -32($t6)    #t7 = a[j]
loop2:  
    bltz $t3, endloop2
    move $a0, $t6
    move $a1, $t7
    jal str_lt
    beqz $v0, endloop2
    lw $t0, 0($t7)
    sw $t0, 32($t7) 
    subi $t3, $t3 1
    subi $t7, $t7 32
    b loop2


endloop2:
    lw $t0, 0($t6)
    sw $t0, 0($t7)

    addi $t2, $t2, 1
    addi $t6, $t6, 32
    b loop1

endloop1:lw $ra, 20($sp)
    lw $fp, 16($sp)
    addiu $sp, $sp, 32 
    jr $ra
```

It seems like the C algorithm I was given overwrites some values when it rearranges them in the array, or perhaps I just translated it wrong.

Comment: How about compiling that piece of code and extracting the assembly?

Comment: @tangrs The point of the assignment isn't to learn how to use `gcc`, it's to write assembly.

Answer (score 0):

you can with gcc with the option -S

1. Create a file named "main.c"
2. Put your code in the file
3. compile with "gcc main.c -S"

a new file will be create in your folder named: "main.s", in this file there will be the assembly code.